# CSS Flex display and centering of paragraphs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to use `display: flex` instead of `float: left` to position paragraphs next to each other in `div`, and then I would like to position all paragraphs in this `div` to the center of the screen (currently with both `display: flex` and `float: left` they are positioned to the left of the screen)

I'm trying to use:

```
#div {display: flex; align-items: center;}
```

in my css but it's not doing the trick.

Can someone more experienced give me a tip on how to do it ? I've been fiddling with all different properties - no matter what I do, text binds to the left.

https://jsfiddle.net/e7bft0eL/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add *justifiy-content* property

> The justify-content property aligns the flexible container's items when the items do not use all available space on the main-axis (horizontally).

```
#test{
    display: flex;
    background-color: white;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h7cn1ts9/)